# Keep only rows if number is greater than... in specific column

Tags: r

This is an example of data:

```
exp_data <- structure(list(Seq = c("AAAARVDS", "AAAARVDSSSAL", 
                                       "AAAARVDSRASDQ"), Change = structure(c(19L, 20L, 13L), .Label = c("", 
                                                                                                          "C[+58]", "C[+58], F[+1152]", "C[+58], F[+1152], L[+12], M[+12]", 
                                                                                                          "C[+58], L[+2909]", "L[+12]", "L[+370]", "L[+504]", "M[+12]", 
                                                                                                          "M[+1283]", "M[+1457]", "M[+1491]", "M[+16]", "M[+16], Y[+1013]", 
                                                                                                          "M[+16], Y[+1152]", "M[+16], Y[+762]", "M[+371]", "M[+386], Y[+12]", 
                                                                                                          "M[+486], W[+12]", "Y[+12]", "Y[+1240]", "Y[+1502]", "Y[+1988]", 
                                                                                                          "Y[+2918]"), class = "factor"), `Mass` = c(1869.943, 
                                                                                                                                                              1048.459, 707.346), Size = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Matt", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Greg", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Kieran"
                                                                                                                                                              ), class = "factor"), `Number` = c(2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(244L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                392L, 396L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to bring your attention to column name `Change` as this is the one which I would like to use for filtering. We have three rows here and I would like to keep only first one because there is a change bigger than 100 for specific letter. I would like to keep all of the rows which contain the change of letter greater than +100. It might be a situatation that there is up to 4-5 letters in change column but if there is at least one with modification of at least +100 I would like to keep this row.

Do you have any simple solution for that ?

Expected output:

```
              Seq          Change     Mass Size Number
244      AAAARVDS M[+486], W[+12] 1869.943 Greg      2
```

Comment: Is it possible to have two values in one instance of Change both greater than 100 for example `M[+567], W[+1520]`?

Comment: Possible, rarely but possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understood your problem statement correctly, but perhaps something like this

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
exp_data %>% filter(str_detect(Change, "\\d{3}"))
#       Seq          Change     Mass Size Number
#1 AAAARVDS M[+486], W[+12] 1869.943 Greg      2
```

Or the same in base R

```r
exp_data[grep("\\d{3}", exp_data$Change), ]
#       Seq          Change     Mass Size Number
#1 AAAARVDS M[+486], W[+12] 1869.943 Greg      2
```

The idea is to use a regular expression to keep only those rows where `Change` contains at least one three-digit expression.

Comment: This might fail if the change is 3-digit negative number like -100. OP hasn't showed any negative numbers in their example so I am not sure if they have it in their actual data.

Comment: @RonakShah True that. Replacing `"\\d{3}"` with `"\\+\\d{3}"` might be a simple fix.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
```

**data.table solution**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(exp_data)

exp_data[, max := max(as.numeric(str_extract_all(Change, "[[:digit:]]+")[[1]])), by = Seq]
exp_data[max > 100, ]

        Seq          Change   Mass Size Number max
1: AAAARVDS M[+486], W[+12] 1869.9 Greg      2 486
```

**dplyr solution**

```
library(dplyr)

exp_data %>% 
  group_by(Seq) %>% 
  filter(max(as.numeric(str_extract_all(Change, "[[:digit:]]+")[[1]])) > 100)

# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   Seq [1]
  Seq      Change           Mass Size  Number
  <chr>    <fct>           <dbl> <fct>  <int>
1 AAAARVDS M[+486], W[+12] 1870. Greg       2
```