# Extract numbers greater than and keep only numbers in a vector

Tags: r

This is an example data:

```
exp_data <- structure(list(Seq = c("AAAARVDS", "AAAARVDSSSAL", 
                                       "AAAARVDSRASDQ"), Change = structure(c(19L, 20L, 13L), .Label = c("", 
                                                                                                          "C[+58]", "C[+58], F[+1152]", "C[+58], F[+1152], L[+12], M[+12]", 
                                                                                                          "C[+58], L[+2909]", "L[+12]", "L[+370]", "L[+504]", "M[+12]", 
                                                                                                          "M[+1283]", "M[+1457]", "M[+1491]", "M[+16]", "M[+16], Y[+1013]", 
                                                                                                          "M[+16], Y[+1152]", "M[+16], Y[+762]", "M[+371]", "M[+386], Y[+12]", 
                                                                                                          "M[+486], W[+12]", "Y[+12]", "Y[+1240]", "Y[+1502]", "Y[+1988]", 
                                                                                                          "Y[+2918]"), class = "factor"), `Mass` = c(1869.943, 
                                                                                                                                                              1048.459, 707.346), Size = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Matt", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Greg", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Kieran"
                                                                                                                                                              ), class = "factor"), `Number` = c(2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(244L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                392L, 396L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to bring your attention to column name `Change` as this is the one from which I would like to extract number greater than `100` and keep all of the numbers from this column in a separate vector. This vector of numbers will be used for filtering another data frame.

Comment: What is the difference from this one?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375673/keep-only-rows-if-number-is-greater-than-in-specific-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep only rows if number is greater than... in specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375673/keep-only-rows-if-number-is-greater-than-in-specific-column)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your previous copy of the question actually had enough explanation to understand what you're doing; this one doesn't. Why?

Comment: The question was made by accident. I was writing previous question in different browser and this one was an old version. No idea how but some time later I have also accidently published this one. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the difference with the last one is creating a numeric vector of all values for matching columns:

```
with(exp_data, {
  f <- \(.) regmatches(., gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", .))
  Change[vapply(f(Change), \(.) any(as.numeric(.) > 100), T)] |>
    as.character() |>
    f() |>
    unlist() |>
    as.numeric()
})

[1] 486  12
```

Consider changing the structure of the `Change` column to not contain multiple variables within one column. That is, consider making a `letter` and `values` column instead.